# Using the .NET Framework security system

Tags: .net, security, code-access-security

I was wondering - do any of you actually use the various classes in the System.Security.Permissions namespace?  I mainly develop desktop/server-side components (i.e., no web) and the general assumption is that FullTrust is always available and no testing is performed on environments for which this is not the case.  Apart from MS source code (EnterpriseLibrary and such), I have yet to see actual, in-use source code that makes use of said constructs.

Is this prevalent, or are we the exception?  I know, of course, that not doing this kind of testing is a problem on our side...

Answer (score 3):

The .NET code access security is more relevant when users run code directly off a server over the internet, in which case they can't necessarily trust it to automatically do things such as access the file system. I don't know of anyone who makes their code available like that, though.

Comment: Precisely the type of answer I was looking for - seems like we're not the only ones...

Comment: +1. The .NET CAS system is complex, unwieldy and generated problems that are hard to debug. Microsoft need to promote it for the Internet sandbox environment.  But for app developers it adds little or no value - especially since most threats come via unmanaged code.

Comment: This is no longer true, and has not been for a long time. It is large, and possibly conceptually complex - but if you know hat you want to do, it is not overly difficult to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

I make lots of use of PrincipalPermissionAttribute to demand the user has necessary access rights (using roles) from the Thread's Principal - saves a lot of manual checking in my business code (obviously the UI should check too and disable buttons etc - this is just the double-check at the back-end).

I find Principal-based security to be very versatily, especially with a custom Principal. But I don't use the CAS stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy your desktop applications with ClickOnce, then the security sandbox can come into play.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen anyone make use of the permit, assert functionality.

I suspect a number of developers are not actually aware of the functionality.

I think it could be useful to restrict calls to dangerous functions.

Its going to depend on what you are doing but who wants to make a deployment more complex than it already is?

Comment: Although useful, I find the implementation very complex.  Maybe that is why it's not very popular or well-known.  I spent considerable time studying the documentation, and wrote some HOWTO-style articles for development group at work - the consensus was that it's hard to use and deploy in practice.